# TYPO3 manual sorting of translated records

Tags: sorting, typo3, translation, extbase, typo3-9.x

When I use in the TCA ctrl-section of an record

```
'sortby' => 'sorting'
```

the translated items are on the same position as the default ones in the backend. But in the frontend the order is wrong. Espacially when some records are for all languages and some are only in the foreign language.

As an example you can use the news extension with manual sorting. This problem still exists in TYPO3 9.5.19.

The number of the ticket in [TYPO3 forge is 70154](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/70154). A solution could be to bind the sorting value on the default language.

Comment: UI-wise the backend can only handle that if you are not in "Localization view" - but I think that's not the point here?

Comment: in TYPO3 v10 you can't disable the Localization view